# Grab value from textfield to use in link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm just starting out learning Rails and am trying to figure out how to grab a value from a text field and pass in a `link_to`. Please show how to add a textfield to form and pass its value in the following line. Thanks!!

```
<%= link_to('Show My Items 1',:controller => 'items', :action => 'myitems', :user_id => textbox_value) %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not totally sure where your values are coming from. If you want to copy the value of one dom element into another, you'd need to use javascript after Rails has rendered `link_to`.

If you have the value of `user_id` at the time Rails is rendering `link_to` (e.g., from a user model `@user` loaded in the controller) you could use *its* value (e.g., `@user.id`).

Other than that, you'd need to provide more details. You can find more information on how `link_to` works here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

Comment: Sorry for not doing a very good job explaining. I think this is a very easy question to answer, I'm just not exactly sure how to ask it. Based on the "link_to" line of code I had in my original post how would I add a textfield on the html.erb page and then grab the value entered into that field and place it in the "textbox_value" in the link_to line? Does that make more sense?

Comment: Could you show the code for the controller, view (html.erb), and model files involved in what you're doing? Maybe I'm missing something glaringly obvious, but it's hard for me to tell if you're just filling out a form, or something that needs fancier front-end javascript.

If you're filling out a form, why does the value of the form field (I assume you're referring to a textarea or text input form field when you say "textfield") need to immediately generate a link on the same page?

Comment: Thanks for trying to help folks but I was able to find the solution using a railscast located here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/37-simple-search-form?autoplay=true. I'm embarrassed to say I really did fight this problem for quite some time before finding the solution. Thanks.